# Initiating a function after window resizing finishes

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I want to initiate a function when user finishes resizing of his browser window.
Please suggest how to do it in either pure JS or jQuery.

Note: I want to raise the event only once and after  user has done browser resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a small delay before running the resize handler using `setTimeout` and keep renewing this timeout until the events stop. This article explains how to do it - http://ajaxian.com/archives/delaying-javascript-execution

Comment: i myself was doing same thing but iwas looking some better solution

Comment: You can use some of the plugins out there (see the comments in the article) but they all essentially do the same thing.

Comment: Or ditch Internet Explorer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize = function() { alert('hi'); };
```

Comment: this will constantly call this function, i want tgis function to be called only once and when user has done with his resizin

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/resize/):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   $('#log').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called.</div>');
});
```

Comment: its clearly written that this fn will be constantly called , i want it to be called after resizing is done